# How to copy objects in single transaction in S3

Tags: amazon-s3

Is it possible to copy a list of objects or sub-directories in a directory in S3 to another directory in a single transaction?

I need this in java

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible.  Individual writes (object creation and copy) are atomic -- they either succeed or they don't -- but S3 is not transactional.  Each copy operation is for a single object, so copying multiple objects requires multiple operations, and each one succeeds or fails independently of the others.

Comment: Workaround: 
ZIP all files together and send them as one file to s3. The application can than read and decompress the ZIP file. 

This step can be done during a deployment (CI/CD) or inside a Java-App.